# TeXShop Problem: No auto-replacement of quotation marks (unless Key Binding activated)

Tags: punctuation, texshop, quotation

I have searched around, but I did not really find a solution to my problem, that is not based on `csquotes`, which I would like to avoid. Presently, I am using TeXShop (which I cannot really avoid) and whenever I use quotation marks I get the symbol "...", which is of course *not* what we would like to get, that is ``...''.

Now, the previous editor I was using was automatically fixing the issue for me, whereas TeXShop is not, unless I choose the – rather annoying – **key binding** option.

Also, for completeness, right after `\documentclass`, I put the line

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
```

Thus, is there a way to fix this problem (which is not based on dropping TeXShop or using `csquotes`)?

Thanks a lot in advance for any feedback!